# efficient way to calculate Fibonacci on a pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

currently, my code is running but it takes a lot of time, I wonder if there is a more efficient way to run this code. 
the thing is I need to calculate the sequence for each row with certain condition:

1. needs to be on the same day
2. can look only at past data (let's say the row n time is `2017-12-13 16:30:00` then I won't want `2017-12-13 16:31:00` in my calculation) 
   my dataFrame looks like this:

```
            date              open    high     low   close  volume  year  day  week hour minute
0      2017-12-13 16:30:00   24.00   24.10   24.00   24.10     800  2017   13   50   16    30
1      2017-12-13 16:31:00   24.10   24.10   24.10   24.20       0  2017   13   50   16    31
2      2017-12-13 16:32:00   24.10   24.10   24.10   25.10       0  2017   13   50   16    32
3      2017-12-13 16:33:00   24.10   24.10   24.10   23.10       0  2017   13   50   16    33
4      2017-12-13 16:34:00   24.10   24.10   24.10   27.10       0  2017   13   50   16    34
...                    ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   ...  ...   ...  ...   ...
579426 2021-04-02 02:55:00  102.75  102.75  102.75  103.75       0  2021    2   13   2     55
579427 2021-04-02 02:56:00  102.75  102.75  102.75  102.75       0  2021    2   13   2     56
579428 2021-04-02 02:57:00  102.75  102.75  102.75  101.75       0  2021    2   13   2     57
```

and I created a function to calculate the Fibonacci sequence as follow:

```
def fibonacci(data):
    fibonacci786up = []
    fibonacci618up = []
    fibonacci382up = []
    fibonacci236up = []
    df = data
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        df1 = df.loc[(data['year'] == row['year']) & (data['week'] == row['week']) & (data['day'] == row['day']) &
                     (data['hour'] <= row['hour']) & (data['minute'] < row['minute'])]
        closeMax = df1['close'].max()
        closeMin = df1['close'].min()
        diff = closeMax - closeMin
        fibonacci786up.append(closeMax - diff * 0.786)
        fibonacci618up.append(closeMax - diff * 0.618)
        fibonacci382up.append(closeMax - diff * 0.382)
        fibonacci236up.append(closeMax - diff * 0.236)
    data['fibonacci786up'] = fibonacci786up
    data['fibonacci618up'] = fibonacci618up
    data['fibonacci382up'] = fibonacci382up
    data['fibonacci236up'] = fibonacci236up
    return data
```

I know as a fact that is not recommended to iterate over a dataFrame on python, but I couldn't figure another way.

Comment: Which column follows the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: in the code, I use the close column to calculate the Fibonacci sequence

Comment: The numbers in the `close` column do not follow a Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: none of the columns make the Fibonacci sequence, i meant my code use the `close` column to calculate the sequence. if you will run the code you will get the sequence.

Comment: In the future, you should add more information to your Stackoverflow questions. For example: what is the input, what is the expected output, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question well but you can group the dataframe by "Year", "Day" and use `.expanding()` on that group:

```py
def fibonacci(x, v=0.786):
    closemax = x.max()
    closemin = x.min()
    return closemax - (closemax - closemin) * v

# assuming your data is sorted:
df["fibonacci786up"] = (
    df.groupby(["year", "day"])["close"]
    .expanding(1)
    .apply(lambda x: fibonacci(x, 0.786))
).values
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       date    open    high     low   close  volume  year  day  week  hour  minute  fibonacci786up
0       2017-12-13 16:30:00   24.00   24.10   24.00   24.10     800  2017   13    50    16      30           24.10
1       2017-12-13 16:31:00   24.10   24.10   24.10   24.10       0  2017   13    50    16      31           24.10
2       2017-12-13 16:32:00   24.10   24.10   24.10   24.10       0  2017   13    50    16      32           24.10
3       2017-12-13 16:33:00   24.10   24.10   24.10   24.10       0  2017   13    50    16      33           24.10
4       2017-12-13 16:34:00   24.10   24.10   24.10   24.10       0  2017   13    50    16      34           24.10
579426  2021-04-02 02:55:00  102.75  102.75  102.75  102.75       0  2021    2    13     2      55          102.75
579427  2021-04-02 02:56:00  102.75  102.75  102.75  102.75       0  2021    2    13     2      56          102.75
579428  2021-04-02 02:57:00  102.75  102.75  102.75  102.75       0  2021    2    13     2      57          102.75
```

---

EDIT:

```py
def fibonacci(x, v=0.786):
    closemax = x.max()
    closemin = x.min()
    return closemax - (closemax - closemin) * v

df["fibonacci786up"] = (
    df.groupby(["year", "day"])["close"]
    .expanding()
    .apply(lambda x: fibonacci(x.shift(), 0.786))
).values
print(df)
```

Comment: well I thought of using a group by clause, but I need to get the max value for the day but only for past data, your code gets me only the current row. i edited the dataframe so it should give different results now. for example the third row max value is `25.10` for the calculation

Comment: @bikoman57 Try the code in my edit. I tested it with your code from the question and the results match. (Don't forget to sort your data by date/time)

Comment: Thank you, it is better but still pretty slow... i would love anthor idea that would make it faster.

Comment: hey, I am still looking for the answer without iterating the data... you have any other ideas?